# problem in automatically installing bundle in crxde

Tags: java, maven, aem, htl

I am building maven project in Eclipse it should automatically update the snapshot bundle in crxde but its not. I am manually installing the bundle in crxde to check page changes. please suggest how crxde should automatically update osgi bundle.

Tried:
I have tried new configuration where I have provided profile as "autoInstallPackage" for the project.

Comment: I guess without further details you will not get an answer.

Comment: Also, are you running the instance in the default 4502 port? If you are using the AEM archetype, by default, autoInstallPackage it assumes you are running on localhost:4502. Also, if you have changed admin credentials, since the archetype uses admin:admin as well. You can update your pom.xml configuration to match your local instance settings.

Answer (score 1):

You dont give much details, but I can give you some context.

CRX/DE does not update the bundle. That is done by the [Sling OSGi Installer](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/osgi-installer.html).
The OSGi installer can process certain artifacts for installation (bundles, configuration, packages, etc). In your case the artifact would be detected by the "JCR provider", which is an OSGi component that listens for changes in the content repository (what you call crx/de) and sends them to the OSGi installer.

Two things could be wrong here:

1. The JCR provider is not picking up your bundle
2. The OSGi installer is not updating it

for the JCR, make sure where you put your bundle. the Provider cannot listen in the entire content tree so by default it only listens up to 4 levels in the tree and only in nodes called 'config' and 'install'. Make sure your bundle location fits this constraints.

If the problem is the OSGi installer  you can check in its felix console tab (http://localhost:4502/system/console/osgi-installer ). This will list the status of all installed artifacts.

If you give more details I could give a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue. In my case my version was not getting updated. Please check if you are using a version or snapshot in your parent pom. It will be helpful if you can share the parent pom.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason may be with the JCR Pause Installer issue.

Navigate to this node /system/sling/installer/pauseInstallation, is there is any child node created. If so, delete them and re build your code.

by the way which version of AEM are you working on?

Comment: its 6.5. Also I have reinstalled and it got fix but cannot do it again and again.